# Java compiler says "missing return statement" even though it would be unreachable

Tags: java, try-catch

I have this method on Java 15:

```
int myMethod() throws MyException {
    try {   
        // do something
        return someInt;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throwingMethod(e);
    }
}
```

`throwingMethod()` wraps the `SQLException` into a `MyException` and throws the latter.  Since the catch clause always throws a `MyException`, it is guaranteed that control will never reach the end of the catch clause.

Why then does the compiler complain about a "Missing return statement" in the catch clause?  Is the best way to fix this to add an unreachable return statement like `return 0;` after the call to throwingMethod() just to make the compiler happy (I see it does)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and throws the latter

The compiler has no way to know this at the call site (*).

If you want to indicate that execution will not proceed beyond that line, declare your method as returning `MyException`, and `throw` the result of calling it:

```
MyException throwingMethod(SQLException e) throws MyException {
   // Either return or throw MyException.
   // Throwing is better if you need to guarantee it will actually be thrown,
   // and can't rely on it being thrown at the call site.
}

// In the catch:
throw throwingMethod(e);
```

---

(*) If you want to know why according to the spec, you can find it at [JLS 8.4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7):

> **If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).**

Your method has a return type (`int`), so it must not complete normally (without e.g. an exception or return).

But in [JLS 14.22](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22):

> - An expression statement can complete normally iff it is reachable.

That is, provided you can reach a method invocation (a kind of statement expression, hence a method invocation followed by a `;` is an expression statement), it is considered that it can complete normally.

However:

> - A break, continue, return, throw, or yield statement cannot complete normally.

So you need the `throw` to make it not complete normally. I suppose you could use `return` instead; but `throw` is clearer in its meaning of "an exception will always occur on this line".

Comment: Alright, this is a new idiom for me.  Clearer indeed.  Solved.